# How to be integrated to any GitHub (OpenSource) project

Tags: github, open-source, project, integration

I'm going to have some free time soon, so i want to increase my Curriculum Vitae, and also gain some expertise working remotely. Is there a part from github or any page where i can see projects to get integrated?

Thanks in advance for any answer.

Comment: I think you need to know them to contribute. But there is plenty of them, a lot of them is mentioned on wikipedia... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're asking for a way to find open source projects that are looking for contributions.  I'd start by checking https://openhatch.org/

Also, please remember that your [GitHub account is not a portfolio, but it's a start](http://petdance.com/2011/08/your-github-account-is-not-your-portfolio-but-its-a-start/). You can't just say "Hey, here's my GitHub account" on your CV and expect the reader to know what's worthwhile in it.